# Preventing a form from submitting in jQuery Validate plugin's submitHandler function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jQuery with the validate plugin at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

I want to prevent the form from submitting after its validation and submission processes done via ajax.
I have the following code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   rules: {...},
   submitHandler: function(form) { 
      alert("Do some stuff...");
      //submit via ajax
      return false;  //This doesn't prevent the form from submitting.
   }
});
```

However, the problem with this is that the `submitHandler` submits the form even though I have a  `return false;` statement at the last line of the handling function. I want prevent the default behaviour and to stop the form from submitting because I have already submitted via ajax.

How should I stop the code from submitting after going through the ajax codes in the `submitHandler` function?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I do it like this and it works exactly how you want it to work:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
    rules: {...},
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        alert("Do some stuff...");
        //submit via ajax
        return false;  //This doesn't prevent the form from submitting.
    }
});
```

Comment: Doing it exactly like this i get 
ReferenceError: e is not defined
e.preventDefault();

Comment: I also get ReferenceError: e is not defined e.preventDefault();, any idea what exactly this means?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but if someone experience the same issue, they should type event.preventDefauld() instead. e is a shortcut for event. If you want e to work, put e between the function brackets, like this function(e).

Comment: Well, e is not really a shortcut, it is a parameter of the anonymous function which gets called when the form gets submitted. If you get a ReferenceError: e error message then you must have made a typo in this line:
    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {

Comment: Excellent, this helped me a lot!

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. The ajax fires the request anyway before the validation.

Answer (score 48):

```
$("#myform").validate({
   rules: {...},
   submitHandler: function(form, event) { 
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Do some stuff...");
      //submit via ajax
   }
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It might help to explain to the person asking the question what `event.preventDefault()` does, and why it works (or provide a reference to it).

Comment: Hooking into the source code of version 1.12.0, it is clear that configuring the `submitHandler` will automatically prevent the default behaviour. Also, and as indicated by @user3157665, the signature of the handler is `submitHandler(form, event)` (the documentation is not in sync with the source code).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because the validation happens before the request is fired.

Comment: If this doesn't work for some reason and the form still seems to be submitting, check if there is an error in the validation rules. If there is a validator error (e.g. invalid rule), the `submitHandler` does not fire.

Answer (score 3):

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1715wqn/3/)

according to jquery plugin validation document.

`submitHandler` (default: native form submit)

the submission method via `submitHandler` below is quoted from [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#submithandler) it should work , but it actually does not work they said that

Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the `form` and the `submit event` as the only arguments. Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

Example: Submits the form via Ajax, using jQuery Form plugin, when valid.

```
$("#myform").validate({   
   submitHandler: function(form,event) {
     event.preventDefault();
      $(form).ajaxSubmit();   
   } 
});
```

i am writing code here what worked for me.
simply call your validayion plugin , and donot include `submitHandler` in your validation function arguments.

instead of submitting and preventing with `submitHandler` use jQuery method of form submission. like below

```
$("form").validate({});

$(document).on("submit", "form", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("submit"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can validate externally without using a submit button:

```
if($("#myform").valid()){
    alert("Do some stuff...");
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting focus on a form input element and hitting the enter key?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `event.preventDefault()` on `submit` event:

```
$("#myform").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: The submitHandler function doesn't seem to take an event parameter.

Comment: @xEnOn Yes, that's why I would separately add `submit` event to the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can code this in a very simple way via "jQuery Walidate".
http://jquery.dop-trois.org/walidate/

There you can code a function, that will be executed on submit.
Look for Callback in the Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it seems that the call: `submitHandler: function(form){` does not take an event argument so it seems that the only solution is a `return false` statement like this:

```
...
submitHandler: function(form) {
    //your code
    return false;
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this way. A patch for a jQuery Validation Plugin bug that it's not fixed even on v1.19.0

```
$('#save_edit_user').on('click', function () {
    var isValid = $("#edit_user").validate().form() && $("#edit_user").validate().element("#edit_user_email");
    //check current ajax call by $.active 
    //the form is not submitted before 0 ajax is running
    if (isValid && $.active == 0){
     // my save logic

    }
});
```