# jquery validations not woking when ajax call is there

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a js code where it is validating a form using jquery validations. and after that it is calling ajax.

```
$('.form').validate({
    rules: {
        ---- 
    }
});
$('#submit').click(function() {

    $.ajax(url,{
        data:data,
        success:onSuccess,
        error:onError,
        type:POST
    });
    return FALSE;
});
```

onSuccess and onError are simple functions.
url is predefined

But with this code its not entering into validations and directly calling ajax whatever might be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not bind a `click` event on submit button. You should place your function on `submitHandler` option of JQuery validation. Like this

```
 $('.form').validate({
    rules: {
    ---- 
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        //your code here..
    }
});
```

Here's the [JQuery Validation docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) to better understand.

Comment: Would you mind accepting this as answer if this helps you?? cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
    rules: {...},
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        alert("Do some stuff...");
        $.ajax(url,{
           data:data,
           success:onSuccess,
           error:onError,
           type:POST
        });
        return false;  
    }
});
```

Read [Preventing a form from submitting in jQuery Validate plugin's submitHandler function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798717/preventing-a-form-from-submitting-in-jquery-validate-plugins-submithandler-func)

Answer (score 0):

Use the submit handler to handle custom submit logic

```
$('.form').validate({
    rules: {

    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        //your ajax save
        $.ajax(url, {
            data:data,
            success:onSuccess,
            error:onError,
            type:POST
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you want to use a custom submit logic, then check whether the form is valid like

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    if(!$('.form').valid()){
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax(url,{
        data:data,
        success:onSuccess,
        error:onError,
        type:POST
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your form class better to use id for form

```
 $(".form").validate({
```

After Validation check better to use submitHandler function which will call ajax like:

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
```