# Prevent form from submitting jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form, the user has to enter 4 values to generate the multiplication table.

To validate the user's input I use jQuery. If the input is not valid (blank, non-integer number, etc) then the error message is displayed. The "Submit" button should only work when the input is valid.

I used this to prevent the form from submitting (source: [Preventing a form from submitting in jQuery Validate plugin's submitHandler function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798717/preventing-a-form-from-submitting-in-jquery-validate-plugins-submithandler-func)):

```
$("#inputForm").submit(function(generateTable) {
   generateTable.preventDefault();
}).validate({
   //code
});
```

Here is the validate.js file:

```
function generateTable() {
   //code
   return false;
}

$(function() {
   $("#inputForm").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }).validate({
      //rules
      //messages
});
```

Here is HTML file:

```
<form id="inputForm" class = 'card p-3 bg-light' class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return generateTable();">
```

The issue is that the form is getting submitted even if the input is not valid. How can I prevent the form from being submitted?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @ScottMarcus sorry I was not clear, my form is getting submitted even if the input is not valid. preventDefault is not working

Comment: @KaanCetinkaya sorry I was not clear, my form is getting submitted even if the input is not valid. preventDefault is not working

Comment: You have two different `submit` handlers set up. The one in JavaScript looks correct, but you also have an inline handler, which should be removed.

   `onsubmit="return generateTable();"`

Comment: @ScottMarcus if I remove the inline handler then the Submit button doesn't do anything when I click it. How should I call the generateTable() function then?

Comment: That’s the point. If you remove the inline handler, only the JavaScript handler remains and that one is currently set to prevent the submit. Call the function from the JavaScript handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the submit function, just use as following.

```
$("#inputForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "name": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        "email": {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "name": {
            required: "Please, enter a name"
        },
        "email": {
            required: "Please, enter an email",
            email: "Email is invalid"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});
```

[See this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/amwmedia/sw87W/)