# What makes preventing the default form submission behavior fail in this use case of jQuery AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have made a **[blogging application in Laravel 8](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0)**.

I am currently working on submitting comments and comment replies via AJAX instead of doing it "classically".

#### The comment form:

```
<div id="commentSuccess-{{ $comment->id ?? '' }}" class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--success">
  Your comment is pending
</div>

<div id="commentFail-{{ $comment->id ?? '' }}" class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--error">
  Failed to add comment!
</div>

<form class="commentForm" method="post" action="{{ route('comment.submit') }}" autocomplete="off">
@csrf
<fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="{{ isset($article->id) ? $article->id : $article_id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $comment->id ?? '' }}">

  <div class="message form-field">
    <textarea name="msg" id="message" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>

    @error('msg')
    <p class="help-block text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
    @enderror
  </div>
  <br>
  <input name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-wide btn--large h-full-width" value="Add Comment" type="submit">
</fieldset>
```

For validation, I use the **[jQuery Validation Plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js)** (v1.19.0) by Jörn Zaefferer

#### The (jQuery) AJAX part:

```
// Validate comment form
$(".commentForm").each(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    form.validate({
        errorElement: 'p',
        errorClass: "help-block text-danger",

        submitHandler: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $fields = form.find('textarea'),
                url = form.attr('action'),
                data = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $(`#commentSuccess-${data.article_id}`).slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
                    $fields.val('');
                },
                error: function() {
                    $(`#commentFail-${data.article_id}`).slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

#### The problem

For a reason I have been unable to find out, the part that should **prevent** "classic" form submission, `event.preventDefault()` does not work.

In the **Network** tab, I see the message:

> Failed to load response data no content available because this request was redirected

#### EDIT

Using `$('#commentSuccess-' + data.article_id)`, by all appearances, fixes the submit prevention problem, but the *success alert remains hidden*.

#### Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this problem?

Comment: The documentation shows nothing of the sort being used in their example to begin with, https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler - so I would assume this isn't actually necessary, and the plugin will prevent normal form submission by default already? It says "Replaces the default submit." right there, and besides AJAX they also give an example there that explicitly calls `form.submit();` at this point, to trigger normal form submission.

Comment: can you try adding `return false;` after your ajax request? `event.preventDefault()` prevents the default functionality of dom elements only.

Comment: @HaseebHassy At what line should I add `return false`?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir after the closing body of ajax request

Comment: __submitHandler gets the form and the submit event as the only arguments.__ console log the parameters maybe event is not the first parameter.

Comment: What happens when you replace `$('#commentSuccess-${data.article_id}`')` with `$('#commentSuccess-{{ $comment->id ?? '' }}')`  or `$('#commentSuccess-' + data.article_id)`and same for failure as well? Is it behaving the same?

Comment: @Adi Using `$('#commentSuccess-' + data.article_id)` does indeed prevent form submission but, even though the comment is posted (I can find it in the database), the success alert `<div id="commentSuccess-5" class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--success">
  Your comment is pending
</div>` is not displayed. :(

Comment: can you post your server responses for both cases? Since if i look at the answer posted by @CodeThing it looks good and should work and correctly said that the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Suggestion for an experiment: After writing a blog in Laravel, do the same in Symfony. One of the main difference you'll notice then is that it has form abstraction and how that changes things for the HTML templating. This will not solve all problems however it may give you better insights. Another experiment could be (and perhaps more compatible with stepping into Laravel) to isolate just the form page with the PHP development server (only using vanilla PHP/Javascript). This is perhaps giving you the fastet results and biggest benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research i have found that event is actually second parameter received in the submitHandler. The first one is form itself.

For some reasons the documentation is not in a sync.

You can try this to prevent the form default form submission.

```
submitHandler: function(form, event) {
      event.preventDefault();
}
```

```js
// Validate comment form
$(".commentForm").each(function(){
  var form = $(this);
  form.validate({
    errorElement: 'p',
    errorClass: "help-block text-danger",

    submitHandler: function(_form, event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $fields = form.find('textarea'),
      url = form.attr('action'),
      data = form.serialize();
      $fields.val('');
      console.log("Submitting to "+url+" with data: "+data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="commentForm" method="post" action="/commentSubmit" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="33">
      <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="1">
      <div class="message form-field">
          <textarea name="msg" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input name="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-wide btn--large h-full-width" value="Add Comment" type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<form class="commentForm" method="post" action="/commentSubmit1" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="message form-field">
          <textarea name="msg" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input name="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-wide btn--large h-full-width" value="Add Comment" type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It does not work. I have multiple forms (because there are comment replies too) and that's why I use a loop.

Comment: Can you elaborate what does not work. Are there any errors you are facing. I have edited answer with sample working code.

Comment: I wonder why `$fields.val('')` does not clear the textarea.

Comment: If you see above snippet and add `$fields.val('')`, you will see it does work. If it is not working in your case the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, that is true, bur I need to display the proper alerts in case of success od failure, respectively. I have `success: function(response)...`

Answer (score 1):

I see an inconsistency in your code. The success/error message elements have this id:

```
<div id="commentSuccess-{{ $comment->id ?? '' }}" ...>
```

Yet the input element you're using to target the success/error message elements has this value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="{{ isset($article->id) ? $article->id : $article_id }}">
```

And then you try to show the element using wrong id:

```
$(`#commentSuccess-${data.article_id}`).slideDown(250)
```

I would rather put all three items (the two alert boxes and the form) inside one parent element and assign a class name to it:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="alert-box--success">...</div>
    <div class="alert-box--error">...</div>
    <form class="commentForm">
       ...
```

Then use:

```
form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").show(...)
```

Comment: You are right. However, getting the `parent_id` from data fails: `console.log(data.parent_id)` logs `undefined` even though `console.log(data)` does log something (that should be useful): `token=oRWnpc0lUPCGrWyMIBp8gcUpsHOzUhIWxUsBbysf&article_id=300&parent_id=300&msg=test&submit=Add%20Commen`.

Comment: Oops. I forgot that jQuery.serialize returns a string, not an object. So you need to use `let article_id = form.find('input[name=article_id]').val()` to grab the id (if you have fixed the id issue).

Comment: The comment is successfully added, but the `<div class="alert-box--error">` element is display, as if there is an error. There _is_ an error. Could it be the `X-CSRFToken`? It yes, what is missing?

Comment: Check network tab in chrome dev tools. Also add `console.log(arguments)` in the error handler. You should then be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try something like this, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16121012):

```js
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
    rules: {...},
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        alert("Do some stuff...");
        //submit via ajax
        return false;  //This doesn't prevent the form from submitting.
    }
});
```

So that you actually apply `preventDefault()` on the `submit` method of the form. Sinde you use the `ajax` call on the specified `submitHandler`. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not so familiar with jQuery validation plugin but I hope putting the validation code inside a **Document Ready** function would make some change.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".commentForm").each(function(){
        var form = $(this);
        form.validate({
           ....
    })
});
```

OR

```
$(function() {
    $(".commentForm").each(function(){
        var form = $(this);
        form.validate({
           ....
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `return false;`, like

```
// Validate comment form
$(".commentForm").each(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    form.validate({
        errorElement: 'p',
        errorClass: "help-block text-danger",

        submitHandler: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $fields = form.find('textarea'),
                url = form.attr('action'),
                data = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $(`#commentSuccess-${data.article_id}`).slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
                    $fields.val('');
                },
                error: function() {
                    $(`#commentFail-${data.article_id}`).slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

See https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/650#issuecomment-67654063

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work for me.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir can you describe how exactly this exact try fails?

Comment: The form's default submit behavior is not prevented when posting a comment *reply*. As a result, the page reloads after submit and the success alert is not within the viewport.  This is why using Ajax is important: so that the user does not have to scroll in order to see that the comment reply was successful. When posting a "normal" (not a reply) comment, AJAX is not needed. This **[feature](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/tree/comment_replies)** has been given me headaches.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir can you create a minimal reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: Yes, it is **[this](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/tree/comment_replies)** GitHub branch (also linked in the question's body).

Comment: @RazvanZamfir can you create an executable example so people will not have to clone in order to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I can not, I wish I cold.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I would create a JSFiddle page if I were you with jQuery included and having two or more forms and your code. Actually that would be a great way for you to find out whether the code you suspect is actually to blame or something else. Separating features while you test are usually very helpful in determining what the problem is.